# calling a button click event

Tags: c#, webforms, buttonclick

Is it possible  to call "button click event" in one web form ,from a button in another web form?
what actually i'm trying to do is, i've  a  link button in second form, when it is clicked, i want the first form to disply and also button in first form to be clicked.
can anyone help me do this?

Comment: You are talking about One WebForm Default.aspx having one Button  and Other WebForm Home.aspx having Link Button, you try to call the Default Button event form Link button Click right??

Comment: yes exactly.that is what i want to do

Comment: can you help me writing c# code for it?

Comment: I think best way to achieve this by Delegate. I have used in WinForms application.

Comment: ok. let me try with that. thanks

Comment: I have posted the sample code for Delgate which I performed in my sample

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using jQuery and have basic knowledge of it. So do it this way:

```
<form id="form1" style="display:none">
 <Asp:Button id="button1" onclick="alert('clicked')" >button1</Asp:Button>
</form>


<form id="form2">
  <Asp:LinkButton url="javascript:void(0);" onclick="call1();">Link button1</Asp:LinkButton>
</form>

<script>
  function call1()
  {
    $("#form1").show();
    $("#button1").trigger("click");
  }
</script>
```

Note: The asp markup written by me can give compilation errors, so please resolve those yourself. I put that just to give you the basic idea of how it is handled.

Comment: is it possible to write c# code ? or this can only be done in the way you answerd

Comment: This way is the best way to do this as this wont call the server event and will happen client side (on the browser) only.

Answer (score 0):

create a Delegate in WebForms (I have used in WinForms)

```
public delegate void LoginDelegate(string s);

 loginAirLineDelegate = new LoginDelegate(DisableToolStripMenuItems);

  public void DisableToolStripMenuItems(string s)
        {
           this.viewToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
            this.bookingToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
            this.existingUserToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
            this.newUserToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
            this.toolStripStatusUserID.Text = "USerID :- "+s;             
           this.LoginUserId = s;
        }
```

I have passed the Delaqgte to other Form with Construtor as argumnet.
I can able to fire the delegate from the second form like this

```
logDelegate(textBoxUserName.Text);
```